# Is it possible to display the HTML tag type using CSS only

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add a visual indication of the HTML tag/element used on a page.
By tag/element I mean if it's an anchor tag I want to display an "a". Likewise if it's a Heading 2 I'd like to display "H2" or similar.

I know I can achieve a similar result using the CSS 'content:' property and pseudo-elements like so:

```
*:before {
    content: attr(title);
}
```

But this only works for HTML attributes as far as I'm aware, and not the tag itself.
Ideally I'd want something like:

```
*:before {
    content: tag();
}
```

Is there anything in CSS that can achieve this result?

**I can't use any javascript. CSS only.**

My only other thought is to map all the tags/elements out in my CSS like so:

```
a:before {
    content: "a"
}
p:before {
    content: "p"
}
h1:before {
    content: "h1"
}
h2:before {
    content: "h2"
}
...
```

...and so on for all tags/elements. But I'm looking for a more dynamic way of doing it.

Comment: Did you just say "dynamic" and "no JavaScript" in the same sentence!? :) best of luck. I'd try creating a class with values like "before...content".

Answer (score 2):

This is an occasion where a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) would come in handy. Then you could simply do:

```
$tags: a, p, h1, h2, etc;

@each $tag in $tags {
  #{$tag}:before {
    content: "#{$tag}";
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/Lwr5ettk/)

Otherwise, the answer to your question (Is there anything in CSS that can achieve this result?), is probably no.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks for sharing this. Unfortunately I'm not using any preprocessors and can't implement in this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're after, but try this:

CSS

```
pre code[class]:after {
  content: 'highlight: ' attr(class);
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

USAGE

```
<pre><code class="h1"><h1>Heading 1</h1></code></pre>
```

This will show some text that's after the element. See the following demo for examples:

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HHxSZjH9aXopypCrQmdA?p=preview)

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've put in here. Thank you. I think though based on this method you would just add a class to everything (or better yet, a data-attribute) and use *:before { content: attr(class) }. There's no need for all the extra <pre> and <code> mark-up. But I'm after a much less invasive approach - ideally not altering the bulk of the HTML at all.

Comment: By what you are describing, you want to put minimal effort into labeling elements. CSS and HTML have limits as to anything "dynamic". You have reached the limits of what CSS can do. When you are exposed to web developing more in the future, you'll see the need for the <pre><code> combo. Data-attributes are more limited than  a class which you'll realize in the future as well as the necessity to learn JavaScript. Unless this is just a hobby of course.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do the job with no CSS and no JS. You just nest the contents in a xmp tag.

```
<xmp> 
  ... 
</xmp>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cowdd/y2b6f354/)

Comment: Thanks Arleigh. Unfortunately I wasn't 100% clear. I still need the markup to display normally just as an additional display element I'm wanting to add some sort of visual indicator of the tag in use. Much like how the CSS pseudo-element using 'content:' works.
Thank you very much for your creative answer though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything in CSS that can achieve this result?

No, there isn't. There is no analog to `attr()` for element names (and even `attr()` requires you to specify the attribute name, so you're not looking for a direct analog either).